# Using Flask: cookies work fine without expiry, but stop working when I add expiry

Tags: python, flask, cookies, python-datetime

I have a Python file that sets a dictionary of cookie data.

The general code goes....

```
resp = make_response(render_template('home.html',options=options)
logging.debug(f"Time is {datetime.datetime.now()}. Expiry is {setExpiryTime()}")
resp.set_cookie("sessionData",json.dumps(sessionData))
return resp
```

And when the user then clicks post, the POST function reads

```
sessionData = json.loads(request.cookies.get("sessionData"))
logging.debug(sessionData)
```

This works fine. The logging info prints the expected expiry date, the cookies are set and read fine. However, if I try and actually set the expiry for the cookie session...

resp.set_cookie("sessionData",json.dumps(sessionData),expires = setExpiryTime())

I get the following:

```
 2022-06-27 23:40:47,692 - DEBUG- Time is 2022-06-27 23:40:47.692785. Expiry is 2022-06-27 23:45:47.692785
```

So the expiry time is set 5 mins into the future, as expected

```
 2022-06-27 23:40:50,668 - INFO- None
```

But now the cookie returns none. So presumably the cookie isn't being set. But the only change I made to the code was to add the function to set the expiry time, and as the logging shows, the expiry time is set five mins in the future. So what am I doing wrong when adding the expiry time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `max_age` parameter of the `set_cookie()`, or use a datetime for your expires:

```
import datetime

expire_date = datetime.datetime.now()

# sets the expiration date by adding the 10 days to the current time.
# modify the parameters to match your desired time.
expire_date = expire_date + datetime.timedelta(days=10)

response.set_cookie("sessionData", json.dumps(sessionData), expires=expire_date)
```

Comment: Thanks. Using max_age seems to have fixed it!

Comment: Great! please mark this as the answer, so it can help others.